# How does the World Ranking work?

Tags: ranking, badminton

Why are athletes ranked the way they are in the BWF world ranking?

For instance, Marc Zwiebler, listed as World #10 as of May 2016, has not won any tournament this year, and has never won a top-level (Superseries) event. How come he's ranked so highly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whenever an athlete competes in a BWF tournament, they get some amount of points. The world ranking is then calculated by the sum of the 10 highest tournament points in the last year. In the [ranking details page](http://bwfcontent.tournamentsoftware.com/ranking/player.aspx?id=11241&player=108860) of a player, these 10 are marked with yellow stars.

The number of points awarded to a player for participating in a tournament depends on two factors: The result and the level of the tournament.

For example, a player who loses in the round of 128 in a Future series (the lowest level) tournament will be awarded 60 points. On the other hand, the winner of the Olympics gets a massive 12000 points. Semifinalists (place 3 and 4) will get about 75%, and quarterfinalists (places 5-8) about 50% of the winner's points.

This ranking rewards consistency; it is perfectly possible that an athlete who regularly reaches the later rounds of tournaments is ranked above one who only manages to win two high-level tournaments per year but does not play any other ones, or an athlete who only competes in the lower-level Future/International Series. For instance, Marc Zwiebler has often reached the quarterfinals at Superseries tournaments (5040 points), and the semi-finals or finals at Grand Prix Gold tournaments (~4000-6000 points).

There are a lot more subtleties, in particular the points awarded at national team events and special rules for doubles and mixed. You can find all of this information, and more, in [Appendix 6 of the BWF General Competition Regulations](http://system.bwf.website/documents/folder_1_81/Regulations/GCR/Part%20III%20-%20Section%201A%20-%20GCR%20Appendix%206%20-%20World%20Ranking%20System.pdf), in particular the table of points in §6.3.